# How can I run a multi language WordPress site in two folders in one install?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, multi-language, configuration

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
www.site.com/en
www.site.com/fr
```

A single WordPress installation but it is translated into French and English and also the theme support, posts and images would reflect.

```
www.site.com/en/this-is-a-post
www.site.com/er/this-is-a-post

www.site.com/en/wp-content/uploads/site-logo.en.jpg
www.site.com/fr/wp-content/uploads/site-logo.fr.jpg
```

What are the best practices ideally without using many plugins - to achieve a multi language and asset driven platform using WordPress? My client wants to use WooCommerce too so currency would come into play also